On a random-walk-like stochastic process with the probabilities following a recursion
Consider the sequence of random variables $(P_n)_{n \ge 1}$ where
$$P_{n + 1} = P_{n} + X_n \frac{\text{sgn}(S_n)}{\sqrt{n}}, \quad P_1 = 0,$$
in which $X_n$ is a random variable with $P[X_n = 1] = 1 - P[X_n = -1] = [P_n]_0^1$ (here $[x]_0^1$ is the projection of $x$ onto $[0, 1]$) and $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$.
Here, $\text{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\quad \text{if } x > 0 \\ -1 &\quad \text{if } x \le 0 \end{cases}$.
(1) Numerical experiments suggest that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n P_n \to \frac{1}{2}$ almost surely, but I haven't succeeded in showing this due to the complicated behaviors of $(P_n)$ and $\text{sgn}(S_n)$.
(2) One of my attempts is to show that $S_n \ge 0$ finitely often, with the hope of simplifying the problem to the update of the form $P_{n + 1} = P_{n} - X_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, which I know how to deal with.
(3) Also, it would be useful if one can show that $P[S_n \ge 0] < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \ge N_0$ for some integer $N_0$ (which is much weaker than (2)).
(4) The initial value (e.g., $P_1 = 0$) is important for the convergence. Setting $P_1 = 1$ leads to a trivial blowing-up.
